# SQL Server CDC is not capturing updates when 2 capture instances reference the same table

Tags: sql-server-2016, cdc

We use CDC to trigger messages sent between two systems in order to keep the data values in sync.

This works really well but now we want to use it to essentially transfer some missing information that wasn't included in the data transfer.

In previous testing I have made an update to a table and set a value to it's current value e.g.

`update customer set name = name;`

and CDC will happily register that as a change and the service picks up the change and generates a composite message for a customer update.

However, I now need to run a similar update that generates two messages, on two different capture instances and only 1 change is being picked up by CDC.

The only difference is that the change that is not being picked up is a capture instance on a table where there is another capture instance that is looking at different changes. the CT table in this case contains no updates.

If I add data, change it or remove it then it captures perfectly for capture instance.

Any ideas ?